Modeling Flip-Flops (RS, T, JK) in Verilog
I encountered an unusual behavior while simulating flip-flops in Verilog using Vivado.
Take, for instance, a four-bit up counter where I used an RS flip-flop for the most significant bit (Q[3]).
There are various ways to model this RS flip-flop. For example, using a behavioral model makes the code quite straightforward like so:
// version 1.
module RS_FF(input CLK, R, S, output reg Q);
     always @ (posedge CLK)
        Q <= S | (Q & ~R);
endmodule

Likewise, it can also be modelled in the following way:
// version 2.
module RS_FF(input CLK, R, S, output reg Q);
    initial Q = 1'b0;
    always @ (posedge CLK)
    begin
        if (~R && S)
            Q <= 1'b1;
        else if (R && ~S)
            Q <= 1'b0;
        if (R && S)
            Q <= 1'b0;        
    end
endmodule

In the first version, however, the simulated output is incorrect; notice how it doesn't reset to 0 after 0xF.

But the second version works correctly:

My question is, what is the problem with the version 1 of the RS flip-flop code?
Four bits up counter code:
module Four_bits_Up_Counter(input CLK, R, output [3:0] Q);    
    wire d0;
    wire t1; 
    wire j2, k2;
    wire r3, s3;
    
    D_FF D0 (.D(d0), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[0]));
    T_FF T1 (.T(t1), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[1]));    
    JK_FF JK2 (.J(j2), .K(k2), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[2]));
    RS_FF RS3 (.R(r3), .S(s3), .CLK(CLK), .Q(Q[3]));

 
    assign d0 = (~R) & (~Q[0]); 
    assign t1 = (R & Q[1]) | (~R & Q[0]);
    assign j2 = (~R & Q[1] & Q[0]);
    assign k2 = (R | (Q[1] & Q[0]));
    assign r3 = R | (Q[3] & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0]);    
    assign s3 = (~R & Q[2] & Q[1] & Q[0]);

endmodule


module D_FF(input CLK, D, output reg Q);
    always @ (posedge CLK)
        Q <= D;
endmodule
                               
module T_FF(input CLK, T, output reg Q);
    // version 1 works with both up and down counter
    initial Q = 1'b0;
    always @ (posedge CLK)
    begin
    if (T) 
        Q <= ~Q;
    end       
endmodule

module JK_FF(input CLK, J, K, output reg Q);
    initial Q = 1'b0;
    always @ (posedge CLK)
    begin
        if (J && ~K)
            Q <= 1'b1;
        else if (~J && K)
            Q <= 1'b0;
        else if (J && K)
            Q <= ~Q;            
    end
endmodule

//module RS_FF(input CLK, R, S, output Q);
module RS_FF(input CLK, R, S, output reg Q);
     //version 1, behaivour model
     //          does not work for up counter
     //           works for down counter
//     always @ (posedge CLK)
//        Q <= S | (Q & ~R);
    
    // version 2, behaivour model
    // works for up and down counter
    initial Q = 1'b0;
    always @ (posedge CLK)
    begin
        if (~R && S)
            Q <= 1'b1;
        else if (R && ~S)
            Q <= 1'b0;
        if (R && S)
            Q <= 1'b0;        
    end

endmodule



module clock_gen (
    input      enable,
    output reg clk
);

parameter integer FREQ = 100000;  // Frequency in kHz
parameter integer PHASE = 0;      // Phase in degrees
parameter integer DUTY = 50;      // Duty cycle in percentage

// Real values must be calculated in procedural blocks
real clk_pd, clk_on, clk_off, quarter, start_dly;

// Start clock signal controlled by enable
reg start_clk;

initial begin    
    // Calculate the timings based on the parameter values
    clk_pd    = 1.0 / (FREQ * 1e3) * 1e9;   // Clock period in ns
    clk_on    = DUTY / 100.0 * clk_pd;      // Clock high duration
    clk_off   = (100.0 - DUTY) / 100.0 * clk_pd;  // Clock low duration
    quarter   = clk_pd / 4;                 // Quarter period for phase
    start_dly = quarter * PHASE / 90;       // Start delay for phase

    // Display calculated values
    $display("FREQ      = %0d kHz", FREQ);
    $display("PHASE     = %0d deg", PHASE);
    $display("DUTY      = %0d %%",  DUTY);
    $display("PERIOD    = %0.3f ns", clk_pd);    
    $display("CLK_ON    = %0.3f ns", clk_on);
    $display("CLK_OFF   = %0.3f ns", clk_off);
    $display("QUARTER   = %0.3f ns", quarter);
    $display("START_DLY = %0.3f ns", start_dly);
end

// Initialize the clock outputs to zero
initial begin
    clk = 0;
    start_clk = 0;
end

  always @ (posedge enable or negedge enable) begin
    if (enable) begin
      #(start_dly) start_clk = 1;
    end else begin
      #(start_dly) start_clk = 0;
    end      
  end
  
  // Achieve duty cycle by a skewed clock on/off time and let this
  // run as long as the clocks are turned on.
  always @(posedge start_clk) begin
    if (start_clk) begin
        clk = 1;
      
        while (start_clk) begin
            #(clk_on)  clk = 0;
            #(clk_off) clk = 1;
        end
      
        clk = 0;
    end
  end 
endmodule

Test bench code:

`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module Four_bits_Up_Counter_TB();
    //reg CLK;
    reg RESET;    
    wire [3:0] Q;
    reg en;
    wire CLK;
    
    clock_gen clk(.enable(en), .clk(CLK));
    Four_bits_Up_Counter TB(.CLK(CLK), .R(RESET), .Q(Q));
    
//    initial
//        CLK = 0;
//        always
//            #5 CLK = ~CLK;
            
     initial
     begin
        en = 1;
        RESET = 0;  
        #20;
        RESET = 1;
        #10;
        RESET = 0;
        #297;
        RESET = 1;
        #100;
        RESET = 0;
        #100;
        $finish;
     end
endmodule


The behavior of version 1 is not the same as the behavior of version 2.
For version 1, Q[3] stays high on the cycle after Q is 0xF because of this term:
(Q & ~R)

Q is 1 from the previous cycle.  R is 0 in the current cycle.  So 1 & ~0 is evaluated as 1 & 1 which results in 1.  This is why Q[3] remains 1.
If you want a simpler version which behaves like your version 2, consider:
module RS_FF (input CLK, R, S, output reg Q);
    always @ (posedge CLK) begin
        if (~R && S)
            Q <= 1'b1;
        else if (R)
            Q <= 1'b0;        
    end
endmodule


I was able to fix it by manually setting the special case of R and S to 0.

I was able to amend the issue by modifying the RS flip flop.
The characteristic equation of RS flip-flop, Q<=S | (~Q & R), is correct.
However, since S & R is illegal by definition, it needs to be handled by forcing it to 0. See below.

module RS_FF(input CLK, R, S, output reg Q);
     //version 1, behaivour model
     //          does not work for up counter
     //           works for down counter
     always @ (posedge CLK)
     begin
        if (R && S)
            Q <= 1'b0;
        else
            Q <= S | (Q & ~R);
     end

